On the orientation of a Jordan Curve
There are few question about this topic here, but I think that none of them answer what I want that is the last claim made by do Carmo in the following:

Let $S$ be an oriented surface. A region $R\subset S$ (union of a connected open set with its boundary) is called a simple region if $R$ is homeomorphic to a disk and the boundary $\partial R$ of $R$ is the trace of a simple, closed, piecewise regular, parametrized curve $\alpha:I\to S.$ We say then that $\alpha$ is positively oriented if for each $\alpha(t)$, belonging to a regular arc, the positive orthogonal basis $\{\alpha'(t),h(t)\}$ satisfes the condition that $h(t)$ “points toward” $R;$ more precisely for any curve $\beta:I\to R$ with $\beta(0)=\alpha(t)$ and $\beta'(0)\neq\alpha'(t)$, we have that $\langle\beta'(0),h(t)\rangle>0.$ Intuitively, this means that if one is walking on the curve $\alpha$ in the positive direction and with one's head pointing to $N$, then the region $R$ remains to the left (Fig.4-27). It can be shown that one of the two possible orientations of $\alpha$ makes it positively oriented.

I am very confident with the result when the boundary of $R$ is regular curve. But how can we ensure that the normal vector $n(s)$ continue to point at the same region when the curve passes by a vertix? I mean, by connectedness it is clear that in each regular piece of the boundary the normal vector always points to the same region (inteior or exterior of $R$). But how can we ensure that the region is the same along all the boundary?

"belonging to a regular arc" precisely means that you do not consider crossing a non-smooth point. This is a piecewise statement

The word "all" in my question perhaps leads to some confusion. I understande that the discussion is about points in regular arcs. But how can I prove that changing pieces of regular arcs does not affect the fact that the normal vector points (for instance) toward R?

Hint: Use the condition "more precisely..." in do Carmo's book. But do Carmo makes a small mistake here, the condition $\beta'(0)\ne \alpha'(t)$ should be replaced by linear independence of these vectors.

I agree that there is a mistake. Using a "slice chart" for a regular piece of arc I can see that his condition after "more precisely..." ensures that the set of points on the (open) regular piece of arc is open and closed in this piece. So the signal of the iner product is the same over this arc. If it is positive, ok. If it negative, we consider the other parametrization. But how can we ensure that if we correct one piece of arc, the other also will have the correct sign?

DoCarmo has more than one book. Can you please give the exact reference (title and page)? Also, what does a positive orthogonal basis mean?

"Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces", page 268
